# Show that $\mathrm{Ann}(M) = (8) \dots$, possible typo?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

The question I was given is stated as follows:

> Let $M = \{1+a_1x+\dots a_7x^7 : a_i \in \{0,1 \} \} \subset \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  With group law $a(x)*b(x) = a(x)b(x) \mod x^8$, M becomes an abelian group.  Show that $\mathrm{Ann}(M) = (8) \subset \mathbb{Z}$ and $\dots$

Looking at the problem, wouldn't $(2)$ be the annihilator?  Maybe this was a typo...  or maybe I'm missing something.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If $M$ is abelian, it is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and I think I'm supposed to find the annihilator as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.  $8$ would be in the annihilator in this case, but so would $2$, as far as I can see.

Comment: Pay careful attention to the addition operation in the $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure: it is $*$, **not** the addition operation on polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible structures of $\mathbb Z$ module. One is just multiplying polynomials by integer. In this structure $2$ ofc is in annihilator but it's not the structure you are interested in. You want to multiply polynomials not add them. So by definition $\mathbb Z$ action on $M$ is just $a\bullet f(x):=f(x)^a$ (where $\bullet$ is multiplication by scalar in M). Remember that $1$ is neutral element of $M$ now to find annihilator we have to notice that $f(x)^8=1$ and for any $i<8$, $(1x)^i\neq 1$. $Ann(M)=(8)$ because $\mathbb Z$ has only cyclic subgroups.

Comment: Actually, $M$ isn't closed under multiplication by integers.

Comment: Of course, I knew I was messing something up.  Thanks for clearing that up for me.  The annihilator is interested in 1, in this case, not 0.  Hurkyl makes a valid point too.  By simple multiplication of an integer, M is not closed.  Consider $1 \in M$ and $2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.  $2*1 = \bar{0} \not\in M$.